# GScam Issues on ARM OMAP4-hf (12.04 server/groovy)

Tags: gscam, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working on getting ROS up and running on my Pandaboard ES using Ubuntu 12.04LTS Server and I am having trouble getting data out of the gscam_publisher. I am using a logitech 9000 pro webcam. Wanted to see if the publisher end requires an x11 host before I start digging into gstreamer code.

The idea is to run the sever on the pandaboard and do the compression, then view it on the other side using something simple like imageview for now. (The other side being my laptop running Linux Mint 14 also with ROS Groovy) I set up my environment variables to the default recommended by gscam:

```
GSCAM_CONFIG="v4l2src device=/dev/video2 ! video/x-raw-rgb,framerate=30/1 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! identity name=ros"
```

the ran as normal with the default cameraparameters.txt file in the gscam/bin directory on the PandaBoard `rosrun gscam gscam`

The output from the gscam node seemed to indicate success from reading the gscam wiki:

```
panda@express:~/groovy/sandbox/gscam/bin$ rosrun gscam gscam
Gstreamer Version: GStreamer 0.10.36
stream is PAUSED.                                                                                                                                                  
[ INFO] [1369592648.077697042]: Successfully read camera calibration.  Rerun camera calibrator if it is incorrect Processing...  .
```

However when I run rostopic echo on any of the topics I get no data coming out (whether I run echo from the panda or the remote host), and I cannot connect with image_viewer. I also note the LED indicator of the camera is turned on, so the device is being accesses.

In RxGraph, the nodes are connected as expected, with gscam_publisher feeding the image_view on my remote host. (the image view window remains greyed out)

Rostopic list also outputs what I would expect:

```
panda@express:~/groovy/sandbox/gscam/bin$ rostopic list                                                              
│/gscam/camera_info                                                                                                     
│/gscam/image_raw                                                                                                       
│/gscam/image_raw/compressed                                                                                            
│/gscam/image_raw/compressed/parameter_descriptions                                                                     
│/gscam/image_raw/compressed/parameter_updates                                                                          
│/gscam/image_raw/compressedDepth                                                                                       
│/gscam/image_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions                                                                
│/gscam/image_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_updates                                                                     
│/gscam/image_raw/theora                                                                                                
│/gscam/image_raw/theora/parameter_descriptions                                                                         
│/gscam/image_raw/theora/parameter_updates                                                                              
│/rosout                                                                                                                
│/rosout_agg
```

Any suggestions on where to go from here or where else to look for assistance? Thanks a lot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63561/gscam-issues-on-arm-omap4-hf-(12.04-server/groovy)/) by [A_Zager](https://answers.ros.org/users/1791/a_zager/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-05-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@jbohren and @rctoris recently created [ros-drivers/gscam](https://github.com/ros-drivers/gscam), which they plan to maintain actively. You might take a look at that, many bug fixes were applied.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-05-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0